# How to add multiple actions in a column in ActiveAdmin in Rails 5.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working with ActiveAdmin in a Rails project. I want to add more than one action in a column in ActiveAdmin view, here is what I am trying to do:

```
index do |company|
  selectable_column
  id_column
  column :name
  column :email
  column :phone
  column :created_at
  column "Actions" do |company|
    link_to 'View', "companies/#{company.id}"

    if company.jobs.present?
      link_to 'View Jobs Posted', {:controller => "jobs", :action => "index", 'q[company_id_eq]' => company.id}
    end
  end
end
```

In the above code I am trying to add two actions in **column "Actions"**, but the thing is it overwrites the first action ('View') and only show the action ('View Jobs Posted').

Answer (score 3):

You can do this way to show multiple link_to under single column same as like default actions, "View Edit Delete".

```
column "Change Status" do |complaint|
  (link_to "Approved", approved_path(product, q: "approved"))  + " " +
  (link_to "Not Approved", approved_path(product, q: "not_approved"))
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of 
`link_to 'View', "companies/#{company.id}"`.

Try : `link_to 'View', admin_company_path(company)`

EDIT 1 : 
or `link_to 'View', company_path(company)` if you want to render the show page of the controller 'company'.

Comment: it's not the answer of my question